# Running `cabal repl` as a super-user (on Linux)

Tags: haskell, usb, sandbox, cabal

The usb package is not on stackage and I created a cabal sandbox to play with it. Code like the package's [example.hs](https://github.com/basvandijk/usb-example) is now working using the `cabal repl` command, but in order to run it fully, one need elevated priviledges (otherwise one gets `libusbx couldn't open USB device /dev/bus/usb/001/001: Permission denied` sort of error messages) (*). On Linux (Ubuntu Trusty), I tried running `sudo cabal repl`, but this does not work.

As recommended on the [Cabal-Install wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Cabal-Install) - but maybe that's only for the `cabal install` command - I added a cabal.config file with a single `root-cmd: sudo` line, in the directory where cabal.sandbox.config is located. This does not seem to work either, `sudo cabal repl` still fails.

**My question** : what is the proper way to run `cabal repl` (or `cabal run`...) with elevated priviledges on linux (Ubuntu)?

(*) One could also change the permissions of the usb devices, and be able to run the program as a normal user, but this is less practical in my situation, and in any case, I'd like to learn how to do it as a super-user rather.

Comment: It sounds very much like you should better see to it that this USB device gets user permission from the OS side. It is generally a bad idea to run anything as superuser, apart from system setup / maintenance operations.

Comment: `cabal exec 'sudo' ghci` might work. `cabal exec shell-script-which-runs-sudo-ghci` will definitely work. `sudo cabal repl` runs `cabal` as a super user, I believe, not the process which it starts.

Comment: Please give more information on the nature of the failure than "this does not work" and "this does not seem to work either". What went wrong? Were there error messages?